# Visualize Bhutan Map with District names and population count of each district using R

Tags: dictionary, state, population, rnaturalearth

This is the code that I used for visualize Bhutan map. I used "rnaturalearth" package in R. Now I want to Vizualize Each district population count on the map.

```
bhutan_states <- ne_states(country = "Bhutan", returnclass = "sf")


world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

bhutan <- world[world$name == "Bhutan", ]

g4 <- ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = bhutan_states, fill = "beige") + theme_minimal() +
  ggspatial::annotation_north_arrow(location = "br")+
  ggspatial::annotation_scale(location = "bl")

ggplotly(g4)
```